# What does 'self' refer to in a @classmethod?

Tags: python, self, class-method

I thought I was starting to get a grip on "the Python way" of programming. Methods of a class accept self as the first parameter to refer to the instance of the class whose context the method is being called in. The @classmethod decorator refers to a method whose functionality is associated with the class, but which doesn't reference a specific instance.

So, what does the first parameter of a @classmethod (canonically 'self') refer to if the method is meant to be called without an instance reference?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

[class itself](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#classmethod):

> A class method receives the class as implicit first argument, just like an instance method receives the instance.

```
class C:
    @classmethod
    def f(cls):
        print(cls.__name__, type(cls))

>>> C.f()
C <class 'type'>
```

and it's `cls` canonically, btw

Answer (score 16):

The first parameter of a classmethod is named `cls` by convention and refers to the  the class object *on which the method it was invoked*.

```
>>> class A(object):
...     @classmethod
...     def m(cls):
...         print cls is A
...         print issubclass(cls, A)

>>> class B(A): pass
>>> a = A()
>>> a.m()
True
True
>>> b = B()
>>> b.m()
False 
True
```

Answer (score 0):

The class object gets passed as the first parameter.  For example:

```
class Foo(object):
    @classmethod
    def bar(self):
        return self()
```

Would return an instance of the Foo class.

**EDIT**:

Note that the last line would be self() not self.  self would return the class itself, while self() returns an instance.

Comment: This is correct, but it is important to note that `cls` is more commonly used as the first parameter to a classmethod.

Answer (score 0):

Django does some strange stuff with a class method here:

```
class BaseFormSet(StrAndUnicode):
    """
    A collection of instances of the same Form class.
    """
    def __init__(self, data=None, files=None, auto_id='id_%s', prefix=None,
                 initial=None, error_class=ErrorList):
        ...
        self.prefix = prefix or self.get_default_prefix()
        ...
```

Even though get_default_prefix is declared this way (in the same class):

```
    @classmethod
    def get_default_prefix(cls):
        return 'form'
```